# Send a notification to user in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, laravel-5.5

This is the scenario. I've User A that send via notification to other User B,C,D... a request to join a group. So in laravel I've created the migration and the controller to handle the notification.

This is the code of GroupController

```
...

foreach ($userINList as $userIN) {
            $userIN = str_replace(' ', '', $userIN);
            $userDBList = User::all();
            foreach ($userDBList as $userDB) {
                $name = $userDB->last_name . $userDB->first_name;
                $name = str_replace(' ', '', $name);
                if (strcmp($name, $userIN) == 0) {
                    $newGroup->users()->attach($userDB->id, ['role' => 'member', 'state' => 'pending']);

                    $notification = User::find($userIN->id);
                    $notification->notify(new GroupNotification($newGroup));

                }
            }

        }

...
```

So in `$notification` I'll try to pass the id of Users that receive the invite and then I use the notify() method to send the notification, but after User A created the group and there aren't notifications to User B, C, D...
I've included the `use Notifiable` in group model. So what's the problem? What I've have to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the code you're doing the following:

1. There is an array of names in the `$userINList` variable
2. You loop through each of the names in the array
3. Remove all spaces in the name
4. Retrieve every `User`
5. Loop through each `User`
6. Remove all the spaces in the `User`'s name
7. Compare the 2 names
8. If the comparison passes then you add the `User` to the group and send a notification

There are quite a few improvements we can make here. For example, we already know which users you wish to notify so you do not need to fetch and compare all users.

Firstly, `$userINList` should *either*  be an array of `User` objects or an array of `User` `id`s — an array of `User` objects is better. Then you can simply iterate through each one.

For example, if you have an array of ids then you could do this:

```
$group = Group::find(1);
$userINList = [1, 2, 3, 4];

User::whereIn('id', $userINList)
    ->get()
    ->each(function ($user) use ($group) {
        $group->users()->attach($user->id, [
          'role' => 'member',
          'state' => 'pending'
        ]);

        $user->notify(new GroupNotification($group));
    });
```

And if you had an array of objects it would be even easier, you could do this:

```
$group = Group::find(1);

collect($users)->each(function ($user) use ($group) {
    $group->users()->attach($user->id, [
        'role' => 'member',
        'state' => 'pending'
    ]);

    $user->notify(new GroupNotification($group));
});
```

Super simple :-)

Comment: I modified a bit your first example and now all is working perfectly. Thank you very much :)